# SSH to GKE node from POD

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-kubernetes-engine

Created the basic **GKE** with **spot** instance to save cost

```
gcloud container clusters create test-cluster \
    --machine-type=e2-medium \
    --num-nodes=1 \
    --spot \
    --zone=us-central1-c \
    --workload-pool=<Project-id>.svc.id.goog \
    --release-channel rapid \
    --addons HttpLoadBalancing
```

Created the **Service Account** and added the **Roles** necessary, image attached below

[image]

**IAM** looks something like this, so ServiceAccount now have Access too, added **Owner** as last option

[image]

This my GKE workload

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: "node-ssh-access@auto-x-244507.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  name: daemonset-access
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: command
data:
  command.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "running sh script on node..!"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: node-gke
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: node-gke
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: node-gke
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: daemonset-access
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      containers:  
      - name: node-gke
        image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli:latest
        command: [ "/bin/sh" , "-c", "tail -f /dev/null" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: commandfile
          mountPath: /test/command.sh
          subPath: command.sh
        - name: script-dir
          mountPath: /test
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          privileged: true
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      volumes:
      - name: commandfile
        configMap:
          name: command
          defaultMode: 0777
      - name: script-dir
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

As of now the workload is an image with **gcloud** **installed**, as ServiceAccount is attached i am able to Access **GCP API** & list the **Instances** running.

i am trying to do the **SSH** from inside of above workload POD with **gcloud** to **GKE** node, however i getting errors.

The command i am tried :

```
gcloud compute ssh gke-test-cluster-default-pool-0e59e91e-q5x6 --zone us-central1-c --impersonate-service-account=node-ssh-access@auto-x-244507.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

2. 

```
gcloud compute ssh gke-test-cluster-default-pool-0e59e91e-q5x6 --zone us-central1-c --impersonate-service-account=node-ssh-access@auto-x-244507.iam.gserviceaccount.com --container=3a7aed0fce5f2
```

3. 

```
 gcloud compute ssh gke-test-cluster-default-pool-0e59e91e-q5x6 --zone us-central1-c --impersonate-service-account=node-ssh-access@auto-x-244507.iam.gserviceaccount.com --container=3a7aed0fce5f2 --internal-ip
```

Not able to do the SSH to **GKE** node from POD. Able to do **SSH** from a **local** machine with **serviceAccount**

The error i am seeing inside POD

[image]

i know we can set the **SSH-Key** to Node, save it in **K8s secret** and use it inside the POD but not looking for that way as **workload** **identity** there, plus i think there is no **OS-login** enabled on my **GKE** or project level too.

Local :

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to acheive ?

Comment: Restart the service on node or run shell script on node, without managing ssh key if can use service account with work identity to auth.

Comment: Why would you need to restart something or run a shell script from inside a pod ? It sounds counter intuitive to me to do this in k8s.

I have never tried to do this and would not recommand it anyway. An other option is to run a privileged pod as a DaemonSet and mount / as a volume inside the pod

Comment: do you mean something like similar right : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72485840/5525824 ? although i was on OKE so that was working for me will check same with GKE missed that privilege one, thanks a ton will give it try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wanted the above case as **Log service** **daemon** on **node** needs to be restarted once there is any change in **Log config (configmap/secret)** to apply **ASAP**.

It worked Maybe there was some other issues with script without any error worked like a charm and was able to **SSH** with

```
gcloud compute ssh gke-test-cluster-default-pool-0e59e91e-q5x6 --zone us-central1-c --impersonate-service-account=node-ssh-access@auto-x-244507.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

inside of the POD.

Another option is **privileged POD** which is similar to i shared in answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72485840/5525824 as suggested by @boredabdel

If you are on older cluster version you might hit on **PodSecurityPolicy** to make sure there is no **PSP** set, however, it is deprecated in the newer releases of **K8s** added as an admission controller part now.